# Error Message R - prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L, : invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument"

Tags: r, machine-learning

I wondered if anyone could help me with identifying and resolving an error term I get when using LCAvarsel.

For context, the library is intended for variable selection in latent class analysis.

```
install.packages("LCAvarsel")
install.packages("poLCA")
library(LCAvarsel)
library(poLCA)

data(carcinoma)
sel1 <- LCAvarsel(carcinoma)
```

The following error is returned:

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  :
invalid value 0 for 'digits' argument

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LCAvarsel/versions/1.1/topics/LCAvarsel

Comment: Not familiar with those packages, but `LCAvarsel()` is calling on `prettyNum()` to do something and `prettyNum()` isn't getting a value for `digits`. Have you tried explicitly adding all the arguments for `LCAvarsel()` e.g. `search =`, `independence =` etc.? One of those arguments may satisfy `prettyNum()`.

Comment: Thanks @LeroyTyrone. I'll try some additional arguments today. Yesterday I made sure parallel = true. I thought perhaps that the solution may be taking too long to converge (or something). However, I'll try more arguments today, thanks

Comment: Did declaring more arguments solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @LeroyTyrone. Thanks for keeping in touch. I personally couldn't resolve it. However, I emailed the package developer for some feedback on the source of the error term. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @EB3112,  Did you get any information from the package developer regarding this error or were you able to resolve it some other way? I am getting the same error message and I have tried contacting the developer too. prettyNum is a base function being called within LCAvarsel. I have used independence = TRUE,  search = "forward", parallel = TRUE but it makes no difference. I think it may have something to do with the item probabilities being zero or close to zero.